# ModelMap usage in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What are the benifits of using ModelMap instead of a simple Map in Spring MVC. I see in the code implementation that they put the datatype of the attribute added in the map as key instead to be made available on the form.

Can anyone explain with an example.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`ModelMap` subclasses `LinkedHashMap`, and provides some additional conveniences to make it a bit easier to use by controllers

- `addAttribute` can be called with just a value, and the map key is then inferred from the type.
- The `addAttribute` methods all return the `ModelMap`, so you can chain method called together, e.g. `modelMap.addAttribute('x', x).addAttribute('y',y)`
- The `addAttribute` methods checks that the values aren't null
- The generic type of `ModelMap` is fixed at `Map<String, Object>`, which is the only one that makes sense for a view model.

So nothing earth-shattering, but enough to make it a bit nicer than a raw `Map`. Spring will let you use either one.

You can also use the `Model` interface, which provides nothing other than the `addAttribute` methods, and is implemented by the `ExtendedModelMap` class which itself adds further conveniences.

Comment: Very nice description. I want to know the difference between `ModelMap.put` and `ModelMap.addAttribute` methods. I know that the put method is available because it extends the LinkedHashMap. Does it make any difference in performance to use any one of the methods. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to point out that this answer is showing word-for-word on another website's post dated April, 2016:

http://crunchify.com/spring-mvc-how-to-access-modelmap-values-in-a-jsp/

Answer (score 2):

`ModelMap.addAttribute` will do NULL check, `ModelMap.put` is inherit from LinkedHashMap

Answer (score 0):

ModalMap extends LinkedHashMap

Implementation of Map for use when building model data for use with UI tools. Supports chained calls and generation of model attribute names.

This class serves as generic model holder for both Servlet and Portlet MVC, but is not tied to either of those. Check out the Model interface for a Java-5-based interface variant that serves the same purpose.